# Compiling multiple C and header files with 1 main

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, program-entry-point

[Files in my directory][1]

Need help compiling in a make file.

So I have this link list assignment i'm doing and the directions were.
stringlist.h is supposed to contain the node and the function prototypes
stringlist.c is supposed to have the functions completed that are defined in      stringlist.h. BUT stringlist.c is not supposed to contain main at all. Then, namelist.c is supposed to contain main and just have the I/O and its just supposed to call the command functions that are in stringlist.c.

So to compile this we are supposed to create a make file. Whenever I try to I get an error because main doesn't exit in one of the c files. Throughout the term we compiled code like this "gcc -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall -g -o  file file.c"
But it doesn't work.

How would I create the make file? Been spending hours and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Jonathan Leffler, the sample Makefile I provided had a few bad ideas. Here's an improvement:

```
# compiler:
CC = gcc

# compiler flags: 
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# the build target executable:
TARGET = executable

# object files to build:
OBJ = namelist.o stringlist.o

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
OBJ := namelist.c stringlist.c
GCC := gcc -g
CFLAGS := -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall

compile: $(OBJ)
    $(GCC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o executable
```

Comment: Tried it out and got an error "make: *** No rule to make target '%(OBJ)', needed by 'compile'. Stop."

Comment: @Programmer Try replacing 'compile' with 'all'.

Comment: hmm weird got a similar error "make: *** No rule to make target '%(OBJ)', needed by 'all'. Stop."

Comment: @Programmer Maybe you could try (with `compile` instead of `all`) running `make compile`?

Comment: @Programmer Well then. I have no idea why this isn't working. Try removing the colons after `OBJ`, `GCC` and `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Alright sounds good! Thank you though! ill try emailing the instructor again and see what he says. I will try those out. Thank you

Comment: @Programmer Oops, I made a typo. Editing the answer. That explains it. If the edit doesn't work, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: @Programmer Did you see the edit I made? It should've fixed the problem. Changed `stringlist.o` and `namelist.o` to `stringlist.c` and `namelist.c`.

Comment: @Programmer If it works, you should mark the answer as accepted. If you don't know how, check out [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) meta post.

Comment: Not sure how to do that just do the arrow up?

Comment: @Programmer No, the small grey check mark beneath the down arrow. It'll turn green once you've clicked it.

Comment: As it stands, the macro name `OBJ` is misleading (to humans) since it specifies source files, not object files.  Of course, `make` doesn't care.  I'm not convinced that a rule called `compile` to create an executable called `executable` is a good idea.  The program will be rebuilt unconditionally each time `make` is invoked.  Once upon a time, it mattered a lot; for big enough projects, it still matters. Normally, you'd have a target `all: executable` as the top-level target, and then have a rule for building `executable` from (source or) object files.